# Indexing a map of maps in Matlab

Tags: matlab, oop, dictionary

Given the following structure:

```
mapA=containers.Map('a', 1);
mapB=containers.Map('b', 2);
mapAB = containers.Map({'A', 'B'}, {mapA, mapB});
```

How do I change the value at: `mapAB('A')('a')`? `mapAB('A')('a')` gives the error: `Error: ()-indexing must appear last in an index expression.`

For reading one could do:

```
p=mapAB('A');
p=p('a');
```

But what about writing at index `('A')('a')`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

containers.Map objects are handle-classes, so to change mapAB('A') in  your example you can also modify mapA:

```
mapA=containers.Map('a', 1);
mapB=containers.Map('b', 2);
mapAB = containers.Map({'A', 'B'}, {mapA, mapB});
mapA('a') = 3;

tmp = mapAB('A');
disp(tmp('a')); % will print 3
```

In case you later on don't have access to `mapA` and `mapB`, you'll have to use a temporary variable for the modification, similar to the above:

```
tmp = mapAB('A');
tmp('a') = 5;
% The following line is not necessary, since you're dealing with handle-objects:
% mapAB('A') = tmp;
```

Comment: Correct! I just read about it in Matlab's doc. Thanks anyway!